# Как сделать из директории модуль maven?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, модули

Возможно ли сделать из уже существующей директории (внутри которой уже есть папки и классы) модуль maven? И можно ли это сделать в intellij idea?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно проверить, присутствует ли в директории, которую необходимо сделать модулем pom файл. Если pom.xml присутствует, но по какой то причине Intellij IDEA модуль не определяет его, то есть следующий вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмем "+", в открывшейся структуре проекта выбираем pom.xml в директории, которая должна быть определена, как модуль.